# An attempt in factory method gives an error "expected class name"

Tags: c++, factory

This is my first time attempting to use the factory method.

### The Idea

A CD Factory is an Item Factory -- so `CDFactory` inherits from `ItemFactory`.

[image: UML Diagram]

I made sure to include the base class `ItemFactory.h` in `CDFactory.h`, but I may have overlooked some important ideas and made a terrible mistake.

#### ItemFactory.h

```
#ifndef ItemFactory_h
#define ItemFactory_h
#include "ItemType.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "CDFactory.h"
using namespace std;
class ItemFactory {
private:
    CDFactory CDFact;
public:
    Item* create(ItemType);
};

#endif
```

#### CDFactory.h

```
#ifndef CDFactory_h
#define CDFactory_h
#include "ItemFactory.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "ItemType.h"
class CDFactory : public ItemFactory {
//                       ^^^^ ERROR: expected class name
public:
    Item* create(ItemType);
};
#endif
```

## A proposed fix

I think I came up with a correction that might work. But in this case, the user have to know to instantiate `CDFactory` and then point to it with a `ItemFactory` pointer. But that seems to me defeat the purpose of the encapsulation. Should the user know about `CDFactory` at all?

#### ItemFactory.h

```
#include "ItemType.h"
#include "Item.h"
class ItemFactory {
public:
    virtual Item* create(ItemType) =0;
};
```

#### CDFactory.h

```
#include "ItemFactory.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "ItemType.h"
class CDFactory : public ItemFactory {
private:
    Item* createClassicalCD();
    Item* createRockCD();
    Item* createDVD();
public:
    Item* create(ItemType);
};
```

Comment: Includes just tell the compiler to copy-paste the file there. Preprocess the two files by hand and you'll notice a problem. Alternatively, try to calculate the size of an `ItemFactory`. It contains a `CDFactory`, which is itself another `ItemFactory`, so it contains a `CDFactory` and so on.

Comment: Which came first, the chicken (CDFactory) or the egg (ItemFactory)?

Answer (score 0):

You have circular includes: the two files include each other. Even if you resolve that, your structure is infinitely recursive:

```
class ItemFactory {
    CDFactory CDFact;
};

class CDFactory : public ItemFactory { 
};
```

I'm guessing that `ItemFactory` doesn't actually need a `CDFactory` member. And that `create` should be `virtual`.

Comment: Ok, I lost the include `CDFactory` and the member `CDFactory` in my `ItemFactory`. How would I refer to the `CDFactory` to make concrete CDs?

Comment: @tomtom `CDFactory factory;`?

Comment: isn't that the member you said `ItemFactory` doesn't need?

Comment: @tomtom Not a member. You would make an object of type `CDFactory`.

Comment: I made an edit to the post, I think that is what you are talking about.